# Why I can't autowire a controller instance into a JUnit class of this Spring Boot application? Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot

I am working on my first Spring Boot application and I am finding some difficulties trying to test my controller class using JUnit.

So I have the following situation, this is my controller class named `PlaceSearcherController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/PlaceSearcher")
public class PlaceSearcherController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PlaceSearcherController.class);


    @Autowired
    private MainSearchServices mainSearchServices;

    @RequestMapping(value = "hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> home() {
        List<AccomodationDTO> accomodationDTOs = new ArrayList<>();

        return ResponseEntity.ok("c è figa");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "getBestListHotel",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<AccomodationDTO>> getHolteListFromPlace(@Valid @RequestBody MainSearchListHotelVO searchObject) {
        List<AccomodationDTO> accomodationDTOs = new ArrayList<>();

        log.debug("search vo in input: " + searchObject);
        try {
            accomodationDTOs = mainSearchServices.getBestHotelListFromPlace(searchObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception: ", e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
        }

        if (accomodationDTOs.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body(null);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(accomodationDTOs);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "getHotelById",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<AccomodationDTO> getHoltelById( Integer id ) {
        AccomodationDTO accomodationDTO = null;

        try {
            accomodationDTO = mainSearchServices.getHotelFromId(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception: ", e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
        }

        if ( accomodationDTO==null ) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body(null);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(accomodationDTO);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "getListRoomByHotelId",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<RoomDTO>> getListRoomByHotelId( Integer hotelId ) {
        List<RoomDTO> roomDTOs = null;

        try {
            roomDTOs = mainSearchServices.getListRoomByHotelId(hotelId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception: ", e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
        }

        if ( roomDTOs==null ) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body(null);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(roomDTOs);
    }

}
```

Then I have this JUnit test class named `PlaceSearcherControllerTest` containing this code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class PlaceSearcherControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private PlaceSearcherController placeSearcherController;

    @Test
    public void placeSearcherControllerTest() {
        System.out.println("placeSearcherControllerTest START");
        System.out.println("placeSearcherControllerTest END");
    }

}
```

At this time the `placeSearcherControllerTest()` method do nothing, I am only trying to run a JUnit test method defined into a JUnit class that obtain the `PlaceSearcherController` controller instance.

So the problem is that running the previous `placeSearcherControllerTest()` test method I obtain the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOrFindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:409)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:323)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:277)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:78)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:152)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:96)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Why is this? How can I solve this issue and correctly obtain the `PlaceSearcherController` instance into my JUnit test class?

The error message say to me that:

> Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

What are these `@SpringBootConfiguration`, `@ContextConfiguration` and `@SpringBootTest`?

Reading here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html it seems to me that `@SpringBootConfiguration` can be used to provide the beans definitions (as a `@Configuration` class in the Spring not using Spring Boot).

My test class is annotate with `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` and reading here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html it say that:

> Spring Boot provides a @SpringBootTest annotation which can be used as
>   an alternative to the standard spring-test @ContextConfiguration
>   annotation when you need Spring Boot features. The annotation works by
>   creating the ApplicationContext used in your tests via
>   SpringApplication

So I think that I have the application context from where take my controller instance. How can I solve it? I think that I am missing something and that the solution have to be pretty simple because I only have a controller class and the test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that your controller is located in `com.example.foo.controller` and your test is in the same directory. Let's now assume that your main class (your `@SpringBootApplication`) is located in `com.example.foo.app`. You've probably tuned the component scan directive since you have an unusual setup.

This has impacts on tests too! The testing support will attempt to locate a `@SpringBootConfiguration` (`@SpringBootApplication` is a `@SpringBootConfiguration`) by looking in the parent package(s) to find a match. If it does not it will throw this exception.

The key is [this section of the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config)

> The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test until it finds a @SpringBootApplication or @SpringBootConfiguration annotated class. As long as you’ve structured your code in a sensible way your main configuration is usually found.

So it searches such match in `com.example.foo.controller`, then `com.example.foo` then `com.example` then `com`. And eventually it gives up and throw the exception.

You haven't given a context in your `@SpringBootTest` so it doeesn't know what context to start. Try to add a reference to your `@SpringBootApplication` in there, something like:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class, webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

If my assumptions are correct, I would highly recommend to review your package structure.

Comment: mmm what is the "classes = MyApp.class"? Is it the main class of the Spring Boot application or what?

Comment: "Try to add a reference to your @SpringBootApplication in there" <-- so, yes.